# stored procedure phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to write a procedure in mysql phpmyadmin.
the procedure is like below:

```
create procedure insert_villa (IN $mtid int,IN $ctid 
int,IN $pro varchar(100),IN $city 
   varchar(100))
   begin

  //variable declare here
   declare $mtid int;
   declare $ctid int;
   declare $pro varchar(100);
   declare $city varchar(100);

   //setting variables
   set @mtid = ($mtid);
   set @ctid   = ($ctid );
   set @pro      = ($pro) ;
   set @city    = ( $city);

 // insert statement 
"INSERT INTO `melk`(`melktypeid`, `contracttypeid`,`province`,`city`)
 VALUES (mtid,ctid,pro,city)";
END//
```

it shows the error like below:
SQL query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_villa( IN $mtid int, IN $ctidint, IN $pro varchar( 100 ) , IN $cityvarchar( 100 ) ) BEGIN //
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

it is my first time using procedure.I don't know much about that. please help me.

Comment: Like any other code you're trying to debug, the first step should probably be to simplify the query and remove variables until you've gotten it down to the simplest piece of code that still gives you the error. That will make it easier to find the problem and also easier for others to read your code and offer advice.

Comment: `//` is not a comment style in MySQL

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, I delete those rows but still It shows error from the line that I declare my variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure can be boiled down to just this

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_villa (IN _mtid INT, IN _ctid INT,  IN _pro VARCHAR(100), IN _city VARCHAR(100))
  INSERT INTO melk (melktypeid, contracttypeid, province, city)
  VALUES (_mtid, _ctid, _pro, _city);
```

Sample usage:

```sql
CALL insert_villa(1, 1, 'Province1', 'City2');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32c1f/1)** demo